# How do you get the end cap width or height values for line objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, width, line

Does anybody know how you can get the endcap width or height values for a line object in C# WPF? Please assume we are using the round endcap (PenLineCap.Round), would like to figure this as a percentage of the line width or some other ratio that would allow me to know the size in pixels of the endcap at any given time. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `PenLineCap.Round` end cap on a WPF line, the line's [StrokeThickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokethickness.aspx) will determine the size of the end cap.